variadic template logger function char null pointer
I have a macro for a logger and it works fine for all data types, but for char * nullptr it just crashes or just exits.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<string_view>

#define LOGGER(...) writet( __FILE__, "::", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, '[', __LINE__, ']', __VA_ARGS__)

template <typename... type>
          static void writet(type &&...args)
          {
        ((std::cout << args << ' '), ...) << std::endl<<std::flush;
       }




int main()
{
  char * test{nullptr};
  void * test2{nullptr};
  LOGGER(NULL,"dsff",1,1.2,nullptr,test2,test,std::string("hello"));
  LOGGER(std::string_view("hi",2));
  return 0;
}

I know I can change
LOGGER(NULL,"dsff",1,1.2,nullptr,test2,test?test:"(nil)");
but I have to this explicit check everywhere, is there any other way I can handle through template itself?

No crash here. When claiming a crash, always mention the compiler with version used. Every info that is needed for a [mcve] should in the post.

Doesn't seem to crash with gcc 13.2.1  (and valgrind doesn't complain as well). And even from version 11.1 it looks ok (demo)

Offtopic: Since C++20 it is possible write a logger without need of macros.

ok.maybe it doesnt crash always,but it will just exit.is there anyway i can handle in template itself?

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?

@user12002570 i am not using debugger.ran on ubuntu gcc 13.1

i know what is the issue.i need a way to handle char * nullptr through template

@Nagaraj It is not clear what you mean by "handle char* nullptr". What is the current output and how does it differ expected output.

Calling operator<<(std::ostream&, char*) with nullptr is undefined behaviour. Just char* a = nullptr; std::cout << a; has the same problem. If you want to add extra check that standard doesn't have, you can't just use fold expressions - you have to separate the calls, so you can handle char* separately and check if the argument is equal to nullptr. Or tell your users that calling LOGGER with char* that is equal to nullptr is UB, just like C++ standard does.

@Yksisarvinen yes but i am not getting how to do function partial template specialization.

Why nullptr when you can ""? And why try char* when you can use std::string_view? Why stick with <iostream> when C++20 <format> and C++23 <print> are available?

am allowed only to use c++17

Why does std::cout output disappear completely after NULL is sent to it

https://godbolt.org/z/Yczr99T6G

There are different ways to only check char* and char const* in the writet function, here is one of them:
namespace detail {
template <typename T>
T&& nullcheck(T&& arg) { return std::forward<T>(arg); }
char* nullcheck(char* p) { return p ? p : "NULL"; }
char const* nullcheck(char const* p) { return p ? p : "NULL"; }
}

template <typename... Args>
void writet(Args&&... args) {
     ((std::cout << detail::nullcheck(std::forward<Args>(args)) << ' '), ...) << std::endl;
}


thankyou.can i have a genric pointer nullcheck,instead of seperate char * and const char *
there will also be unsigned char * and const unsigned char *

Sure, you can instead write template <typename T> T* nullcheck(T* p) { return p ? p : "NULL"; } instead of the char overloads
